# How to make declaration in PGAdmin III (version : 1.22.1)

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgscript

My question might sound silly, but here's the problem.
I just want to declare this in a pgscript:

```
DECLARE @I, @J, @T, @G;
```

according to [this](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.22/pgscript.html?highlight=declare), but I get this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "@"
LINE 1: DECLARE @I, @J, @T, @G;
```

What am I missing? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Click "Execute pgScript" button or press "F6" key.